# Text hidden for some reason normally - shows on hover - Basic CSS

Tags: css

Does anyone know how to show the Address Bar in the boxes always, not just on hover/mouse over?

*You have to put your mouse pointer over a box to see the address I am talking about.

http://search.epicmountainhomes.com/i/snyderville-basin-real-estate

Thanks!

Comment: Look for the `opacity` property and the `:hover` pseudo selector.

Comment: You both are awesome! It is just one of those things that I have been staring at for a while and just couldn't see the obvious answer. Thank you very much, Dasar, Ibu, and Ovokuro!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change `opacity: 0` to `opacity: 1` for `.IDX-grid .IDX-streetInfo` in your stylesheet.

Answer (score 1):

When you hover over `.IDX-resultsCell` it's changing the opacity of `.IDX-streetInfo`.
Set the opacity to 1 to show all the time...

```
.IDX-grid .IDX-resultsCell .IDX-streetInfo {
    opacity: 1
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
.IDX-grid .IDX-streetInfo {
background: none repeat scroll 0 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.45);
 color: #F2F2F2;
font-size: 11px;
font-weight: bold;
left: 6px;
overflow: hidden;
white-space: nowrap;
text-overflow: ellipsis;
padding: 5px 5px 0;
position: absolute;
right: 6px;
text-align: right;
text-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8), 0 0 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
top: 8px;
opacity: 0;
-webkit-transition: top 0.2s ease 0s, opacity 0.2s ease 0s;
-moz-transition: top 0.2s ease 0s, opacity 0.2s ease 0s;
-o-transition: top 0.2s ease 0s, opacity 0.2s ease 0s;
-ms-transition: top 0.2s ease 0s, opacity 0.2s ease 0s;
transition: top 0.2s ease 0s, opacity 0.2s ease 0s;
}
```

Look For this code block in your CSS stylesheet. Find Opacity which is currently set to 0. Change it to Opacity:1; Opacity:0; means transparent. Setting it to 1 will make it fully visible.